# Not able to download GWT Plugin in my Eclipse Indigo / Juno

Tags: eclipse, gwt, eclipse-plugin

I have been trying since long time to integrate Google Plugins to my Eclipse Indigo(3.7) and Juno(4.2).

Tried both URLs.

For Juno -> [https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2](https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2%5D) and

For Indigo -> https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7

Followed URL https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.2 . But I am not getting options as mentioned in images in the URL.

I get only "Developer Tool" and "NDK Plugins".

I also tried downloading plugins archive for both and getting three options

- Google Plugin for Eclipse (required)
- GWT Designer for GPE(recommended)
- Google App Engine Tools for Android (requires ADT)

But after hitting "next" its only allowing me to proceed with "Google App Engine Tools for Android (requires ADT)" not with other two.

Its little frustrating now. Can you guide me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Maybe https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq#multiuser

Comment: Not possible... I am the admin.

Comment: What happens if you try it with a clean eclipse installation? Just download it and run it in an empty workspace.